# Arduino Serial.println weird bug

Tags: loops, button, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying out arduino and have programmed some button with a state switch. If it was "on" then it turns "off" and versa.

```
#include <Bounce.h>

const int buttonPin = 2;     
const int ledPin =  6;      

int ledState = HIGH;     
int a = LOW;            
int b = LOW;  
Bounce push1 = Bounce( buttonPin,5 );

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  push1.update ( );
  int x = digitalRead(push1.read());
  if (x != b) {
    if (x == HIGH) {
      if (a == HIGH) {
        a = LOW;
        }
        else {
          a = HIGH;
        }
  }
  else {
    }
  }

digitalWrite(ledPin, a);
Serial.println(a);  // Weird thing
b = x;
}
```

It works well, but weird thing is that when i was programming i added some Serial prints to monitor output thru COM. Then after it all worked well i wanted to eliminate `Serial.println(a);` but it doesn't work then!

The loop doesn't respond to my button pressing at all.
Am I missing something? What could cause this kind of thing ?
Maybe i missed something, so fresh eye would be great : )

**Thanks a lot!**

Comment: I suspect the `Serial.println` is acting as a delay.  Trying replacing the `Serial.println` with a `delay`, e.g. `delay(100);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the state of the button by calling `digitalRead(push1.read())`.

This is almost certainly incorrect (but I haven't used the Bounce library). `push1.read()` is reading the state of the button, presumably HIGH (0x1) or LOW (0x0).  This button state value is then being used as the pin to read in the call to `digitalRead`. So, it looks to me like you are reading the state of either pin 0 or 1, not pin 2 where the button is. If I remember correctly pins 0 and 1 are the hardware serial port.

Change:

```
int x = digitalRead(push1.read());
```

to:

```
int x = push1.read();
```

and see if that works better.

I suspect the `Serial.println(a)` is a red-herring, it would certainly be acting as a delay.  There may be a weird interaction happening between the serial port and your code as I believe you are reading the "button state" (`x`) from the serial port not the button.

Comment: unbelievable! but simplifying code to `int x = push1.read();` Fixed the whole thing! Big ups Comrade!

Answer (score 1):

mttrb is correct in that

```
int x = digitalRead(push1.read());
```

is the source of the problem. One can see in on [Arduino's web page of the library](http://playground.arduino.cc/code/bounce) and its example may be initially miss leading.

```
digitalWrite(LED, bouncer.read());
```

It is worth noting though the

```
int x = push1.read();
```

As per the library code is simply a periodic read of the digitalread(buttonPin); Not much real benefit. Where it is usually more beneficial to

```
if (push1.fallingEdge()) {
...
```

Noting that falling/risingEdge() functions are stateful, and these member functions clear the statechange. So that new edges are correspondingly flagged for reading.