# The difference of 1 character in Serial.println() breaks my button debouncing (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, debouncing

Yes, the title makes no sense, my problem makes no sense either.

(using Arduino Uno, Eclipse as an IDE and the Sloeber plugin on Win 10)

I'm just trying to read a simple button press and use software debouncing to clean up the signal from it. I followed the tutorial here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce

I will eventually have three buttons to read and debounce but I'm just trying to get the "Save" button working right now. Once I have it actually printing "save" when it should I plan to add code to write to the EEPROM. That comes later though.

My program enters the:

```
//if the save reading is different to the save state
if (SaveReading!=SaveState){
  Serial.println("savereading != savestate");
  SaveState=SaveReading;
  if (SaveState==HIGH){
    Serial.println("Save");
  }
}
```

statement ONLY if I have a certain amount of characters being printed to the serial monitor in the preceding section:

```
//if the save button is in a different state to the last saved state:
if (SaveReading!= lastSaveState){
  //reset debounce timer
  lastDebounceTime=millis();

  Serial.println("change detected");
  Serial.println("Save reading= ");
  Serial.println("1");

  Serial.println("last 123=");
  Serial.println("2");

}
```

Originally all the numbers being printed were words, but in an effort to isolate WTF was going on I deleted text until it broke. I think it is dependent on the number of characters as I've merged several of the Serial.println() lines and kept the number of characters the same and it still works.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with this that makes it dependent on stuff printing to the serial monitor? Its been ages since I've messed with Arduino so I may be missing something simple.

I did try playing with a delay() instead of the serial.println() but that didn't seem to work and I don't really want an actual delay there anyways.

I did see this Q: [Arduino Serial.println weird bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496886/arduino-serial-println-weird-bug)

But I checked and I don't *think* I've got the same problem although the symptom certainly looks the same.

Can anyone see what I'm missing? I did consider scrapping this and using the Bounce2 library but figured if I could do it myself I'd actually know what was going on.

Full code below:

```
// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int hallPin = 12;     // the number of the hall effect sensor pin
const int SaveButtonPin=11; //GREEN
const int ResetButtonPin=10;//YELLOW
const int UnitButtonPin=9;  //BLACK

// variables will change:
int hallState = 0;          // variable for reading the hall sensor status
int oldhallState=0;         //to store previous hall-state reading.
int counter=0;

//save button
int SaveState=LOW;
int lastSaveState=LOW;

//reset button
int ResetState;
int lastResetState=LOW;

//unit button
int UnitState;
int lastUnitState=LOW;

//instantaneous readings
int SaveReading;  //temporary variable for checking debounce status.
int ResetReading;
int UnitReading;

unsigned long lastDebounceTime=0;
unsigned long debounceDelay=50;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);//initialize the Baud-rate for the Serial Monitor.

  //set input pins as inputs
  pinMode(SaveButtonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ResetButtonPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(UnitButtonPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(hallPin, INPUT);

}

void loop(){
  //check the save button.
  SaveReading=digitalRead(SaveButtonPin);

  //if the save button is in a different state to the last saved state:
  if (SaveReading!= lastSaveState){
    //reset debounce timer
    lastDebounceTime=millis();

    Serial.println("change detected");
    Serial.println("Save reading= ");
    Serial.println("1");

    Serial.println("last 123=");
    Serial.println("2");

  }

  //if (time since program started)-(time at which the save state changed) is greater than the
  //debounce delay, then:
  if((millis()-lastDebounceTime)>debounceDelay){

    //if the save reading is different to the save state
    if (SaveReading!=SaveState){
      Serial.println("savereading != savestate");
      SaveState=SaveReading;
      if (SaveState==HIGH){
        Serial.println("Save");
      }
    }
  }


  ResetReading=digitalRead(ResetButtonPin);
  UnitReading=digitalRead(UnitButtonPin);

  // read the state of the hall effect sensor:
  hallState = digitalRead(hallPin);

  if (hallState == LOW) {
    if(hallState!=oldhallState){
      counter++;
      Serial.println(counter);
    }
    oldhallState=hallState; //set hall state of (t-1)
  }
  else {
    oldhallState=hallState; //set hall state of (t-1)
  }

  lastSaveState=SaveState;

}
```